# Maven release plugin fails : source artifacts getting deployed twice

Tags: java, maven, nexus, maven-release-plugin

We are using the maven release plugin on hudson and trying to automate the release process.
The release:prepare works fine. When we try to do the release:perform , it fails because it tries to upload a source artifact twice to the repository.

Things that I tried,

1. removing the profile which does include the maven source plugin from the super pom ( did not work)
2. specifying the goals on hudson for release as -P!attach-source release:prepare release:perform. Which I thought will exclude the source plugin from getting executed. (did not work).
3. tried specifying the plugin phase to some non existent phase in the super pom.(Did not work)
4. tried specifying the plugin configuration, forReleaseProfile as false. ( guess what?? Did not work too)

It still spits out this error.

```
[INFO] [DEBUG] Using Wagon implementation lightweight from default mapping for protocol http
[INFO] [DEBUG] Using Wagon implementation lightweight from default mapping for protocol http
[INFO] [DEBUG] Checking for pre-existing User-Agent configuration.
[INFO] [DEBUG] Adding User-Agent configuration.
[INFO] [DEBUG] not adding permissions to wagon connection
[INFO] Uploading: http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases//com/yyy/xxx/hhh/hhh-hhh/1.9.40/hhh-hhh-1.9.40-sources.jar
[INFO] 57K uploaded  (xxx-xxx-1.9.40-sources.jar)
[INFO] [DEBUG] Using Wagon implementation lightweight from default mapping for protocol http
[INFO] [DEBUG] Using Wagon implementation lightweight from default mapping for protocol http
[INFO] [DEBUG] Checking for pre-existing User-Agent configuration.
[INFO] [DEBUG] Adding User-Agent configuration.
[INFO] [DEBUG] not adding permissions to wagon connection
[INFO] Uploading: http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases//com/xxx/xxxx/xxx/xxx-xxx/1.9.40/xxx-xxx-1.9.40-sources.jar
[INFO] [DEBUG] Using Wagon implementation lightweight from default mapping for protocol http
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Error deploying artifact: Authorization failed: Access denied to: http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx-config/1.9.40/xxx-xxx-1.9.40-sources.jar
```

Any help regarding this will be really appreciated.

Comment: Issue to vote: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSOURCES-8

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Try running `mvn -Prelease-profile help:effective-pom`.
You will find that you have two execution sections for `maven-source-plugin`

The output will look something like this:

> ```
>     <plugin>
> ```

```
      <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.4</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>attach-sources</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

To fix this problem, find everywhere you have used `maven-source-plugin` and make sure that you use the "id" attach-sources so that it is the same as the release profile.  Then these sections will be merged.

Best practice says that to get consistency you need to configure this in the root POM of your project in build > pluginManagement and **NOT** in your child poms.  In the child pom you just specify in build > plugins that you want to use maven-source-plugin but you provide no executions.

In the root pom.xml:

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <!-- This id must match the -Prelease-profile id value or else sources will be "uploaded" twice, which causes Nexus to fail -->
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>    
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

In the child pom.xml:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Similar blog post: http://blog.peterlynch.ca/2010/05/maven-how-to-prevent-generate-sources.html

Comment: Thanks, @Bae. I was unaware of the `effective-pom` goal. Your answer helped me track down a problem that I had been fighting for most the day.

Comment: I'm finding that `attach-sources` is still being called switch with this same configuration.  Anyone have a clue?

`Line 640: [INFO] [DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar (attach-sources)`

`Line 660: [INFO] [DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar-no-fork (attach-sources)`

Comment: Had the same issue. Got it resolved. My pom file had maven-source-plugin with the goal of jar-no-fork.But maven root pom file has the same plugin with the goal of jar. Hence the effective-pom generated has both the goals. This causes the duplicate attempt to push sources.jar. Once i removed the jar-no-fork goal in my pom, the default jar goal was the only one left and the build succeeded. For my usage it did not matter if it was jar or jar-no-fork.

Comment: I had problem performin release:prepare release:perform from jenkins build in order to publish to nexus and issue was that it was doing it twice, first for the artifact second for sources-jar. This answer helped me. +1 I saw people mention reverting back to maven 3.0.5 but that bring up some https protocol errors, so have chosen this solution, and it works on maven 3.6.3

Answer (score 37):

I know this question is old but it was google hit #1 today so I'll add my answer appropriate for recent versions of maven 3.

The symptom is that sources and javadoc jars are deployed twice when doing a release build with some versions of maven 3. If you're using maven to deploy your artifacts to a Sonatype Nexus repository that only allows a release artifact to be uploaded once (which is totally reasonable behavior), the build fails when the second upload attempt is rejected. Argh!

Maven versions 3.2.3 thru 3.3.9 have bugs - see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5868 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5939. Those versions generate and deploy sources and javadoc jars twice when doing a release.

If I read the Maven issue tracker correctly, those bugs are not scheduled for fix as of this writing (the burned 3.4.0 release probably affected these).

Instead of a complex tweak to my pom, my simple workaround was to fall back to Maven version 3.2.1.

Comment: After serious head banging against the wall... YES, this is the only viable solution, THX! Since we're still locked on JDK 6 for some while, and Maven 3.3.+ requires Java 7, rolling back to Maven 3.2.2 was the only acceptable option.

Comment: Seems to be my issue too. As of Maven 3.6.1 now, those issues still not fixed.

Comment: Still not fixed in 2019, and the workaround still works. You can find the official packages here: https://www.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/

Comment: Worked for me, downgraded from 3.6.1 to 3.0.5.

Comment: Update June 2020: supposed to be fixed in Maven version 3.7.0

Comment: Update April 2021: still happening in Maven verion 3.8.1

Comment: Update June 2021: supposed to be fixed in Maven version 3.8.2. p.s. can you believe how long this has been going on??

Comment: Update Jan 2022: I no longer have access to a Sonatype Nexus repo, would someone please verify that this behavior was fixed in maven version 3.8.2?

Answer (score 11):

Just having hit the same problem, I analyzed it a bit. `mvn release:perform` evaluates the release.properties file, then checks out the tag in a temporary directory and invokes there something like

```sh
/usr/bin/mvn -D maven.repo.local=... -s /tmp/release-settings5747060794.xml
    -D performRelease=true -P set-envs,maven,set-envs deploy
```

I tried to reproduce this – manually checked out the tag produced by `release:prepare` and invoked this:

```
mvn -D performRelease=true -P set-envs,maven,set-envs deploy
```

I got the same result: It was trying to upload the -sources.jar twice.

As noted by [qualidafial](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13253/qualidafial) in a comment, setting `performRelease=false` instead omits one of the two attachments of the same file.

I don't really have an idea how the [deploy plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) (or any other plugin) uses this property.

We can provide this parameter as a configuration to the maven-relase-plugin:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I now added the `<useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>` line to all the POMs, and it looks like releasing now works without an error message.

Comment: Alternatively, add useReleaseProfile=false as a property.

Comment: Worked for me for version 3.6.1.

Answer (score 6):

I have been struggeling with this issue for a while and have finally been able to resolve it in our infrastructure. The answers here didn't help me, as we didn't have multiple executions of the source plugin goals and the configuration seemed fine to us.

What we did miss out was to bind the execution of the source plugin to a phase. Extending the example by Bae, including the line **`<phase>install</phase>`** to the execution resolved the issue for us:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.4</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>attach-sources</id>
      <phase>install</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>jar</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I suspect the solution lies in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041610/maven-plugin-executes-multiple-times-during-build); different plugins seem to be invoking the jar goal / the attach-sources execution. By binding our execution to a certain phase, we force our plugin only to be run in this phase.

Comment: it helped me understand that the issue was in the maven-source plugin. I have temporary disabled it and now it works

Answer (score 5):

This was happening to me when running

```
mvn install deploy
```

I avoided the problem by instead running

```
mvn deploy
```

(which implies install). In my case only one artifact was being attempted to be uploaded twice, and that was a secondary artifact (maven-jar-plugin was setup to build a secondary jar in addition to the one built by the default-jar execution).

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR

Disable execution with id `attach-sources` fixes this problem, if you cannot modify your parent poms.

--

This answer is a supplementary for @Bae's answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10794985/3395456

My problem is the same, when running `mvn -Prelease-profile help:effective-pom`, I have two execution sections for maven-source-plugin

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.4</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>attach-sources</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>jar</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>jar</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The top voted answer just recommends a best practice to remove unnamed (anonymous) `execution` to avoid duplicated binding. But what if I cannot remove it, because I cannot change the parent pom?

There is one way to disable one `execution`, not the anonymous one, but the one with id `attach-source`. And it also works for uploading `xx-javadoc.jar` twice.

So under my `pom.xml`, I can explictly override the plugins settings, by disabling the execution with id `attach-source`.

```
  <!-- Fix uploading xx-source.jar and xx-javadoc.jar twice to Nexus -->
  <!-- try to disable attach-sources, attach-javadocs execution (bind its phase to none) -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>attach-sources</id>
        <phase>none</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
        <phase>none</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
  </plugin>
```

References:
[Is it possible to override executions in maven pluginManagement?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17443003/3395456)

Comment: I thinks it works. because the plugin configure will be merged by default . 
The goal will be merged , so as describe on the first answer, will has multi-goals. 
But the `phase` configuration will be override. finally , the configuration named `attach-sources` in the execution section will be overwritten with new phase named `none` . so the configuration with id `attach-sources` will be not bind to any build lifestyle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the probem is in the release plugin, I think you've got the `xxx-sources.jar` attached two times - that's why the duplicate upload. Why is there a duplicate attachment is hard to tell without seeing the POM. Try running `mvn -X` and checking the log for who attaches `xxx-source.jar` another time.

In any case, a good workaround on Nexus would be having a staging repository where you can upload releases several times - and when everything's ready you just close/promote the staging repo. Check the [Sonatype OSS setup](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Basically, the error message is issued when an artifacts is sent to Nexus twice. This may be twice to the same Nexus repository or even across different repositories within the same Nexus.

However, the reasons for such a misconfiguration may vary. In my case, the artifacts were uploaded correctly during a mvn clean deploy build step in Jenkins, but then failed when a second deploy had been attempted. This second deploy had been configured in a Jenkins post build step "Publish artifacts in Maven repository".

Answer (score 0):

Maven plugins in parent and child poms should not have execution. As per standard convention, define all plugin with execution/goals in parent pom in plugin management section. Child pom should not redefine above details, but mention only the plugin (with artifactId, and version) that needs to be executed.

I had similar issue with maven-assembly-plugin with parent pom as below:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

And Child pom had maven-assembly-plugin as below:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>xyz</finalName>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xyz-distribution</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Removing the `<executions>` from child pom rectified the issue.
The effective pom had 2 executions performed causing the duplicate install to Nexus repo.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW this issue was breaking our build for a while and the answer was none-of-the-above.
Instead I had foolishly set the seemingly innocuous appendAssemblyId to false in a maven-assembly-plugin for an artifact that gets attached (read deployed, released) with our main artifact. E.g.:

```
    <execution>
        <id>ci-groovy-distrib</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>my-extra-assembly</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>

            <!-- This is the BUG: the assemblyID MUST be appended 
                 because it is the classifier that distinguishes 
                 this attached artifact from the main one!
            -->
            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            <!-- NOTE: Changes the name of the zip in the build target directory
                       but NOT the artifact that gets installed, deployed, releaseed -->
            <finalName>my-extra-assembly-${project.version}</finalName>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
```

In summary:

1. the assembly plugin uses the assemblyId as the *classifier* for the artifact, hence an essential part of it's unique GAV coordinates in maven terms (actually it's more like GAVC coordinates - C is the classifier).
2. the name of the file *installed*, *deployed*, or *released* is actually built from these coordinates. It **is not the same as the filename you see in your target directory**. That's why your local build looks good, but your release will fail.
3. The stupid  element only determines the local build artifact name and plays no part in the rest of it. It's a complete red-herring.

**Summary of the summary:**
*The 400 error from Nexus was because our extra attached artifact was being uploaded over top of the main artifact, since it had the same name as the main artifact, because it had the same GAVC coordinates as the main artifact, because I removed the only distinguishing coordinate: the classifier derived automatically from the assemblyId.*

The investigation to find this was a long and tortuous path the answer was right there all along in the docs for maven-assembly:

> **appendAssemblyId**
>
> - **boolean**
> - Set to false to exclude the assembly id
>     from the assembly final name, and to create the resultant assembly
>     artifacts without classifier. **As such, an assembly artifact having the
>     same format as the packaging of the current Maven project will replace
>     the file for this main project artifact**.
> - Default value is: true.
> - User property is: assembly.appendAssemblyId.

From http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html#attach

The extra bold is mine. The docs should have a big flashing warning here: "Set this to false and abandon all hope"

I got some help from this answer about a different problem [maven-assembly-plugin: How to use appendAssemblyId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482839/maven-assembly-plugin-how-to-use-appendassemblyid/38484021#38484021)
The explanation there from tunaki really helped.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue. Artifacts were getting deployed twice and the resultant build was failing.

Checked and found that the issue was in Jenkins Script. The settings.xml was called twice. Like:

*sh "mvn -s settings.xml clean deploy -s settings.xml deploy -U* .....

which caused the issue.
Updated this line and it worked like a charm:

**sh "mvn clean deploy -s settings.xml -U** .....

Answer (score -1):

with nexus thix configuratio nworked for me

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score -2):

I configured the maven release plug-in with releaseProfile=false and dont execute the source artifacts profile. Which did the trick.

```
<build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                            <arguments>-P!source-artifacts</arguments>
                            <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
                            <goals>-Dmaven.test.skip=true deploy</goals>
                    </configuration>    
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

Comment: Downvoted--this is a sledgehammer approach.  Only <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile> is actually necessary to solve the problem, but you're turning off source artifacts altogether, and skipping tests--that's like turning off all compiler warnings because they annoy you.  Also, for completeness I'd like to see an explanation of what the "useReleaseProfile" does and why it helps.

Comment: I'm downvoting as well. Skipping tests is never the right answer. In my case, the effective POM showed that one of our projects actually had two executions of the deploy goal. Removing the extraneous execution was the solution.