# Maven plugin executes multiple times during build

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-plugin

I have a Maven project with multiple overlapping profiles.  I want to display the active profiles at the beginning of every build.  So I put the following into the `pom.xml <build>` section:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>display-active-profiles-at-start-of-build</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>active-profiles</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The problem is that the plugin executes multiple times during the build:

1. At the beginning of the build (during the `validate` phase).
2. When `jar:jar` executes.
3. After `source:jar` / during `pre-integration-test` (?), when Jetty is being started.

Similar results when specifying `<phase>initialize</phase>`.  Is there a way to get this to only run at the beginning of the build?

Answer (score 5):

The reason it executes several times, is because one of your plugins is executing another lifecycle as part of its mojo.

`source:jar` definitely does it, as specified by [its documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-mojo.html).

> Invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase generate-sources prior to
>   executing itself.

`jar:jar` usually does not, but it may be that you have another plugin that spins off another lifecycle.

In case of generation of source jar, you generally don't need another lifecycle, and plugin authors recognized this by implementing [`jar-no-fork` mojo](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-no-fork-mojo.html).

You may substitute it for default `jar` mojo, by following steps described here -> http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Thanks.  This may shave serious time off my build as frontend/npm/bower/ember steps are expensive when executed once let alone three times

Answer (score 0):

I´ve had similar problem on an automated bamboo pipeline. I solved it by setting an specific maven-source-plugin version on my pom.xml

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
  </plugin>
```

Rootcause was related to my a Java Version (Java 8). Due to the absence of the plugin defintion/version, apparently maven would automatically select an imcompatible maven-source-plugin to use.