# Is it possible to override executions in maven pluginManagement?

Tags: maven

In parent POM, I have:

```
 <pluginManagement>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                       <id>execution 1</id>
                       ...
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                       <id>execution 2</id>
                       ...
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                       <id>execution 3</id>
                       ...
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        <pluginManagement>
```

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to disable some `<execution>` in sub-projects, e.g, only run `execution 3` and skip 1 and 2?
2. Is it possible to totally override the executions in sub-projects, e.g. I have an `exection 4` in my sub-projects
   and I want only run this `execution` and never run execution 1,2,3 in parent POM.

Comment: The proposed recommended solution using per-project POM properties for profile activation won't work because only global system properties can be used for this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A quick option is to use `<phase>none</phase>` when overriding each execution. So for example to run execution 3 only you would do the following in your pom:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>execution 1</id>
                <phase>none</phase>
                ...
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>execution 2</id>
                <phase>none</phase>
                ...
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>execution 3</id>
                ...
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
  ...
</build>
```

It should be noted that this is not an officially documented feature, so support for this could be removed at any time.

The recommend solution would probably be to define `profiles` which have `activation` sections defined:

```xml
<profile>
  <id>execution3</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>maven.resources.plugin.execution3</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>
  </activation>
  ...
```

The in your sub project you would just set the required properties:

```xml
<properties>
    <maven.resources.plugin.execution3>true</maven.resources.plugin.execution3>
</properties>
```

More details on profile activation can be found here:
http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Activation

Comment: While I agree that you should be using profiles for these, main problem here is poorly defined parent poms (that you cannot modify) that leak their configurations.