# Inherit only some properties or some plugins from parent poms

Tags: maven, ant, oracle-adf

We have Oracle ADF and SOA projects that are built using custom Ant scripts, instead of normal Maven build. The same Ant plugin is configured differently for ADF and for SOA. The file structure isn't driven by the type of the project, but can be mixed, meaning:

```
- parent pom
    - ADF
    - SOA type1
    - SOA type2
```

How can we set in the `pluginManagement` different versions of Ant plugins, and the children to pick whatever type of Ant plugin they want. As I know you can only pick what plugins you want, but not what flavor of same plugin.
I don't want to complicate my inheritance structure just for this. I need the structure to remain as it is, for release purposes.

The same I want with properties, I want to have some types of properties in central places, and a project to be able to use them, but also inherit the parent pom (for release purposes). Sort of like inherit from multiple parents.

I don't want to be tight by the need of properties and plugins (which are general for all projects, not just mine). I need to keep my pom structure clean, for release purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [`profiles`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html). They allow for the ability to customize a particular build for a particular scenario.

You can define multiple profiles in your parent pom each containing their own ant `<plugin>` section. Each profile would also have `activation` section. Then in your child modules you would have them activate the appropriate profile.

I'll try and give an example using some sudo code:

**parent pom**

```xml
<profile>
    <id>adf-project</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- adf specific ant plugin config -->
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>adfBuild</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>soa-project</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- soa ant plugin specific config -->
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>soaBuild</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
</profile>
```

Then in your soa module pom you would have the following:

```xml
<project ...>
    <properties>
        <soaBuild>true</soaBuild>
    </properties>
</project>
```

This will then automatically activate that profile and use the correct ant plugin configuration.

Another option would be to define the plugin as normal but with multiple `executions` (one execution for soa and one for adf) and then in the child poms override each execution with a `phase` of `none` for those executions that you do **not** want to run. It should be noted that this latter approach is not recommended. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17443003/1570834) for more details on this.

Comment: Yeah, the later looks like a workaround. Is the first option with profiles an option generally accepted ?

Comment: @CosminVacaroiu Yes profiles are generally accepted - we use them extensively in our project. You can get more background information on them from the official maven web site here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html or from the sonatype book here: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/profiles.html

Comment: Yes, we are using profile extensively, but I didn't knew I can have plugins in profiles. We were using them only to set properties. I was asking if it's ok to use profiles for plugins. For example we were using profiles for building from root some children (by setting modules), and it was wrong and we removed it. So using profiles for too many things might not be cool.

Comment: We use profiles for plugin definitions, and there are plenty of examples on the internet where this is the case, so I would say it is okay.