# Nexus accepts upload but says it failed

Tags: java, maven, nexus

When I execute `mvn release:perform` on a parent POM, the server is responding with this error about one of the child projects (filenames redacted):

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file
>   (default-cli) on project: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not
>   transfer artifact from/to repository: Failed to transfer file.
>   Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Bad Request.

However, all the files for this child project *are* successfully uploaded! I see a new directory (named after the release version number) and it contains all the .jar, .pom, .md5, and .sha1 files one would expect.

I don't have access to the Nexus server, but I'm wondering what might cause this and how to fix it. Is it possible that Maven is trying to upload this particular child project twice? If so, why would Maven be doing this and how can I stop it?

**UPDATE:** If you're having the same problem, check out the answer with the most upvotes in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251488/maven-release-plugin-fails-source-artifacts-getting-deployed-twice). I ran `mvn help:effective-pom` and found that the project in question actually had two executions of the deploy phase. Removing one of those executions solved my problem.

Comment: Is the version that you are trying to deploy already present ?

Comment: @wrongAnswer: No. When the error first occurred, I thought maybe that was the problem, so I explicitly deleted the artifact's new directory (along with the directory of another child project that uploaded without errors) and tried again. This resulted in the same problem: Both the child projects uploaded, but the second gave the "Bad Reqeust" again even though it uploaded successfully.

Comment: Can you give the full error ...

Comment: Here is the error that I'm getting for a similar setup: https://gist.github.com/arun-gupta/4cb82e44a29561c3d6a4

Comment: You don't have access to Nexus even though you're deploying to localhost:8081?

I would try performing a wget on the artifact and see if it truly is there and if it is valid and built with the timestamp you expect (in the manifest file).

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue, releasing a [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) multi-module project. An error occured the first time but the deploy goal had already contact [nexus](/questions/tagged/nexus) and then create the appropriate path. Assuming that a "release" repo is a write-once one, the second time I trggered it, [nexus](/questions/tagged/nexus) refuse to overwrite the path.

So, in such a case, you might ask your admin to delete the repo ... or create a new release.

PS : better late than never ;)