# Jenkins Nexus Upload Plugin Failing

Tags: jenkins, nexus

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFmVf.jpg)Am using Nexus Artifact Uploader plugin to upload my .ear file to Nexus. Its working fine for all jobs except one. In this particular job am supposed to download an existing .ear file from nexus, do some editing to config files within the ear, repackage it as UpgradeTrue.ear and UpgradeFalse.ear and upload both the ears to the same location from where I have downloaded the original .ear.

Strangely it tries to upload the file which doesnt exist. Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Jenkins Log Snippet:

[image: Jenkins Log Snippet]

Comment: Provide full configuration of the plugin

Comment: Possible a dup of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003271/nexus-accepts-upload-but-says-it-failed), try with `mvn help:effective-pom` to see if there are two executions of the deploy phase?

Comment: Also turn on debugging logs for more information.

Comment: The most common reason is that you are trying to re-deploy an artifact into a repository which does not allow redeployment.  Check the "deployment policy" in your hosted repository configuration.  If it is set to "disable redeploy" it means you cannot redeploy an artifact which is already in the repository.  Note that this is the default setting for Nexus release repositories, since redeploying release artifacts is a maven anti-pattern.

Comment: This information I found in https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213464668-Troubleshooting-Artifact-Deployment-Failures . May be this is causing the redeploy to fail but still the question is why is it changing the file name while uploading the ear.