# Maven maven-deploy-plugin always upload twice

Tags: maven, maven-deploy-plugin

I've a problem when publishing component to a Nexus repository, Maven upload the file twice:

- first time with maven-deploy-plugin groupId/artifactId/version parameters (that's what I want)
- second time with pom groupId/artifactId/version parameters (that's what I DON'T want)

I launch packaging/deployment with the following command (see pom.xml file at the bottom):

`mvn clean package deploy:deploy-file -e -f pom.xml`

Here is the snippet of maven output console when handling deploy phase (the 6 first lines are correct but notice the 2 last lines with pom groupId/artifactId/version):

```java
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy-file (default-cli) @ assemblage-playbook ---
Uploading: http://urlRepo:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/COMPOSANTS/COMPOSANT-A/1.0/COMPOSANT-A_1.0.tar.gz
Uploaded: http://urlRepo:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/COMPOSANTS/COMPOSANT-A/1.0/COMPOSANT-A_1.0.tar.gz (2 KB at 2.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://urlRepo:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/COMPOSANTS/COMPOSANT-A/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://urlRepo:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/COMPOSANTS/COMPOSANT-A/maven-metadata.xml (321 B at 4.6 KB/sec)
Uploading: http://urlRepo:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/COMPOSANTS/COMPOSANT-A/maven-metadata.xml
Uploaded: http://urlRepo:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/COMPOSANTS/COMPOSANT-A/maven-metadata.xml (321 B at 1.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://urlRepo:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/com.mycompany/assemblage-playbook/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Uploading: http://urlRepo:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/com.mycompany/assemblage-playbook/1.0-SNAPSHOT/assemblage-playbook-1.0-20150209.154427
```

Here is my pom.xml file:

```java
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>assemblage-playbook</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>assemblage-playbook</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../../../parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assembly/playbook-assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <finalName>COMPOSANT-A-1.0</finalName>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <file>target/COMPOSANT-A-1.0.tar.gz</file>
                            <repositoryId>nexus</repositoryId>
                            <groupId>COMPOSANTS</groupId>
                            <artifactId>COMPOSANT-A</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0</version>
                            <generatePom>false</generatePom>
                            <packaging>tar.gz</packaging>
                            <url>http://urlRepo:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Any idee to solve it ?

Thanks for your help.

[EDIT]

With the command line `mvn deploy:deploy-file -e -f pom.xml`, it works well (whitout `clean package`), but I need to package before deploy...

Comment: Which file is uploaded twice? I don't see any file being uploaded twice from the maven log (only Uploading & Uploaded).

Comment: ADMINAPP-15.1.0.3.tar.gz file, renamed assemblage-composant-1.0-20150209.101242-1.tar.gz the second time (the name of pom artifact)

Comment: Why do you have added maven-deploy-plugin to package phase. If you like to deploy artifacts to nexus let maven do the job via `deploy` phase. Furthermore the profile `compoant-admin` looks really strange cause this will cause trouble.

Comment: I do this because I have other components like "composant-admin" which depends on several modules. If I use maven deploy, each module will be uploaded and I can't customise group, artifact items at runtime.

Comment: I just update the original post to be more clear as you mention  @khmarbaise it wasn't clear (and you were right^^)

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251488/maven-release-plugin-fails-source-artifacts-getting-deployed-twice

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The maven-deploy-plugin uploads the file you specify then uploads the all project attached artifacts.  The maven-assembly-plugin by default attaches the output file to the project attached artifacts.  This makes the upload happen twice for you.

The fix is to this to your maven-assembly-plugin configuration.

```
<attach>false</attach>
```

Comment: and i get: The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact