# Maven trying to deploy the same artifact twice

Tags: java, maven

I'm using Maven to build my project, but when I run the command `mvn clean package deploy`, it tries to deploy the artifact twice. I have the build-helper-maven-plugin plugin configured to attach an ear file that I create using a custom plugin.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifacts>
                            <artifact>
                                <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.ear</file>
                                <type>ear</type>
                            </artifact>
                        </artifacts>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

When I disable build-helper-maven-plugin, the remaining artifact (only the pom) is uploaded only once.

What should I do to let Maven deploy the extra ear file only once?

Erates

**EDIT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>my.artifact.id</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>My Project</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <scm>
        <!-- Config -->
    </scm>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <!-- Config -->
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <!-- Config -->
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- My Dependencies here -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                            <includeGroupIds>my.group.ids.that.need.to.be.included</includeGroupIds>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
                <artifactId>my.custom.plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <params>
                        <!-- My params -->
                    </params>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>my-custom-goal</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Release Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <goals>clean package deploy</goals>
                    <tagBase>https://my.tagbase</tagBase>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifacts>
                                <artifact>
                                    <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.ear</file>
                                    <type>ear</type>
                                </artifact>
                            </artifacts>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <modules>
        <!-- My Modules -->
    </modules>
</project>
```

Comment: Why do you use build-helper-plugin to attach an ear file? Are you using maven-ear-plugin or packaging ear ? (Full pom file would be helpful).

Comment: @khmarbaise I've added the complete pom (removed some sensitive information). The ear file is added using a dependency and adjusted with the custom plugin. That's why there isn't a maven-ear-plugin

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251488/maven-release-plugin-fails-source-artifacts-getting-deployed-twice

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you are using module and trying to do weird things in your parent pom (dependency-plugin, build-helper etc.). In a parent there should never be an execution like you have in your pom. You should make the appropriate configuration/execution within the appropriate modules cause this definition will be inherited of all childs.

Would you like to create an ear file? Than you should use packaging `ear` and your ear file will simply being deployed by using `mvn deploy`.

Furthermore you seemed to misunderstand the life cycle cause if you call:

```
mvn clean package deploy
```

this can be reduced to:

```
mvn clean deploy
```

cause the package life cycle is part of deploy so i recommend to read the [life cycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) information.

Comment: [Here you have an example how an javaee build can look like](https://github.com/khmarbaise/javaee/).

Comment: I'm doing mvn clean deploy now and now it only uploads once. Thx!!

Comment: You should cleanup your parent pom cause it's wrong despite the fact that it currently works as you expect.