# maven deploy upload older and current version

Tags: java, maven

I have checked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251488/maven-release-plugin-fails-source-artifacts-getting-deployed-twice) but of no avail, moreover my project is not multi-module maven project. [pom.xml](https://github.com/tarun3kumar/seleniumtestsframework/blob/master/pom.xml)  file

## Issue

My project version is 5.5 and which I am trying to deploy to maven repo. But `mvn ddeploy` fails with following error -

```
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Nexus Staging Rules Failure Report
[ERROR] ==================================
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Repository "comseleniumtests-1056" failures
[ERROR]   Rule "RepositoryWritePolicy" failures
[ERROR]     * Artifact updating: Repository ='releases:Releases' 
does not allow updating artifact='/com/seleniumtests/seleniumtestsframework/5.4/seleniumtestsframework-5.4-sources.jar'
[ERROR]     * Artifact updating: Repository ='releases:Releases' does not allow updating artifact='/com/seleniumtests/seleniumtestsframework/5.4/seleniumtestsframework-5.4-javadoc.jar'
[ERROR]     * Artifact updating: Repository ='releases:Releases' does not allow updating artifact='/com/seleniumtests/seleniumtestsframework/5.4/seleniumtestsframework-5.4.pom'
[ERROR]     * Artifact updating: Repository ='releases:Releases' does not allow updating artifact='/com/seleniumtests/seleniumtestsframework/5.4/seleniumtestsframework-5.4.jar'
[ERROR] 
[ERROR]
```

I am on `Apache Maven 3.3.9` and was able to deploy till version 5.4 but deploying version 5.5 ends up uploading version 5.4 again. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To be sure it does not hit cache or anything you could try `mvn clean deploy`

Comment: Is your project version *actually* 5.5 in the pom? Because I would expect this error to occur if it were 5.4 and you were trying to deploy a second time. Please post the pom itself (maybe not the specific dependencies, but at least the general structure, with the `<parent>`, artifactId, groupId, and version, etc.)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I had posted pom.xml file. It is an opensource project.

Comment: @AlbertBos `mvn  clean deploy` did the trick :) Please post it as answer and I would accept it.
Though I yet don't get why it was trying to upload older version 5.4 along with 5.5 :-?

Comment: Links to external code are OK on SO. You need the code to be *in the question itself.*

Comment: Noted. Given that answer is not related pom.xml itself I am leaving the question as it is unless some one objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be sure it does not hit cache or anything you could try `mvn clean deploy`.
I think maven checks if the source files have been changed. If only the pom.xml gets updated, the `target/` folder won't be recreated and that one still contains 5.4