# Bintray 409 conflict - mvn release plugin uploading jar twice?

Tags: maven-release-plugin, bintray

I'm struggling to push releases to Bintray in full.

From what I can tell, the issue seems to be caused by the maven release plugin trying to push the sources jar twice -- hence the HTTP 409 conflict response being returned.

---

So far I've not been able to locate the cause. Help would be appreciated!

- I can see the jars on bintray up to the point that it fails, indicating it doesn't seem to be a credentials issue
- Appending `;override=1` to the end of the url seemingly allows the release to succeed (I'm still new at this, so not 100% sure what I should be seeing)
- Another collaborator is able to release fine - he's using a slightly older version of maven (downgrading from 3.6 to 3.5 is my next step, but it seems unusual/odd/unlikely?)
- mvn test/package/install etc are fine - no concerns there
- the version number is a full release number, not a snapshot (e.g. 1.2.3, not 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT)
- edit: similar results are found using both Windows and Ubuntu (virtualbox guest)

---

Here's a snippet of what I believe to be the relevant parts of the mvn output, but can post more if needed.

```
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:3.0.0-M1:install (default-install) @ YYY-core ---
[INFO] [INFO] Installing /home/XXX/YYY/target/checkout/YYY-core/target/YYY-core-VERSION.jar to /home/XXX/.m2/repository/com/github/YYY/YYY-core/VERSION/YYY-core-VERSION.jar
[INFO] [INFO] Installing /home/XXX/YYY/target/checkout/YYY-core/pom.xml to /home/XXX/.m2/repository/com/github/YYY/YYY-core/VERSION/YYY-core-VERSION.pom
[INFO] [INFO] Installing /home/XXX/YYY/target/checkout/YYY-core/target/YYY-core-VERSION-sources.jar to /home/XXX/.m2/repository/com/github/YYY/YYY-core/VERSION/YYY-core-VERSION-sources.jar
[INFO] [INFO] Installing /home/XXX/YYY/target/checkout/YYY-core/target/YYY-core-VERSION-sources.jar to /home/XXX/.m2/repository/com/github/YYY/YYY-core/VERSION/YYY-core-VERSION-sources.jar
[INFO] [INFO] Installing /home/XXX/YYY/target/checkout/YYY-core/target/YYY-core-VERSION-javadoc.jar to /home/XXX/.m2/repository/com/github/YYY/YYY-core/VERSION/YYY-core-VERSION-javadoc.jar
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0-M1:deploy (default-deploy) @ YYY-core ---
[INFO] [INFO] Uploading to bintray-YYY-ZZZ: https://api.bintray.com/maven/YYY/ZZZ/YYY/;publish=1/com/github/YYY/YYY-core/VERSION/YYY-core-VERSION.jar
[INFO] [INFO] Uploaded to bintray-YYY-ZZZ: https://api.bintray.com/maven/YYY/ZZZ/YYY/;publish=1/com/github/YYY/YYY-core/VERSION/YYY-core-VERSION.jar (1.2 MB at 112 kB/s)
[INFO] [INFO] Uploading to bintray-YYY-ZZZ: https://api.bintray.com/maven/YYY/ZZZ/YYY/;publish=1/com/github/YYY/YYY-core/VERSION/YYY-core-VERSION.pom
[INFO] [INFO] Uploaded to bintray-YYY-ZZZ: https://api.bintray.com/maven/YYY/ZZZ/YYY/;publish=1/com/github/YYY/YYY-core/VERSION/YYY-core-VERSION.pom (4.9 kB at 824 B/s)
[INFO] [INFO] Uploading to bintray-YYY-ZZZ: https://api.bintray.com/maven/YYY/ZZZ/YYY/;publish=1/com/github/YYY/YYY-core/VERSION/YYY-core-VERSION-sources.jar
[INFO] [INFO] Uploaded to bintray-YYY-ZZZ: https://api.bintray.com/maven/YYY/ZZZ/YYY/;publish=1/com/github/YYY/YYY-core/VERSION/YYY-core-VERSION-sources.jar (781 kB at 96 kB/s)
[INFO] [INFO] Uploading to bintray-YYY-ZZZ: https://api.bintray.com/maven/YYY/ZZZ/YYY/;publish=1/com/github/YYY/YYY-core/VERSION/YYY-core-VERSION-sources.jar
[INFO] [INFO] Uploading to bintray-YYY-ZZZ: https://api.bintray.com/maven/YYY/ZZZ/YYY/;publish=1/com/github/YYY/YYY-core/VERSION/YYY-core-VERSION-javadoc.jar
[INFO] [INFO] Uploaded to bintray-YYY-ZZZ: https://api.bintray.com/maven/YYY/ZZZ/YYY/;publish=1/com/github/YYY/YYY-core/VERSION/YYY-core-VERSION-javadoc.jar (3.8 MB at 218 kB/s)
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Reactor Summary for YYY-parent VERSION:
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] YYY-parent ...................... SUCCESS [ 18.058 s]
[INFO] [INFO] YYY-core ........................ FAILURE [01:37 min]
[INFO] [INFO] YYY-core-testing ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] [INFO] YYY-B-core ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] [INFO] YYY-B-testing ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time:  01:56 min
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: 2020-03-28T03:33:28Z
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0-M1:deploy (default-deploy) on project YYY-core: ArtifactDeployerException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.github.YYY:YYY-core:jar:sources:VERSION from/to bintray-YYY-ZZZ (https://api.bintray.com/maven/YYY/ZZZ/YYY/;publish=1): Failed to transfer file: https://api.bintray.com/maven/YYY/ZZZ/YYY/;publish=1/com/github/YYY/YYY-core/VERSION/YYY-core-VERSION-sources.jar. Return code is: 409, ReasonPhrase: Conflict. -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your `pom` file isn't attached, I am relying on this [example](https://github.com/bintray/bintray-examples/tree/master/maven-example).

The `409 conflict` is because you are publishing the same file name to the same path **twice.**

From the attached logs it looks like you are deploying `YYY-core-VERSION-sources.jar` twice (it has 2 entries of *Installing* and *Uploading* in the log). This means that you are trying to `publish` a jar with the same name and to the same path. This causes the conflict.

I don't know from the input you gave why you have two identical `sources` files. One solution, as you have mentioned, is to use the override flag `;override=1` as shown in the [Upload API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/BT/Bintray+REST+API#BintrayRESTAPI-ContentUploading&Publishing) example. I would also take a look why you have 2 files while another collaborator has, probably, only one.

Comment: It looks like I'm coming across the same problem as in [this related question from 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10794985/429733) (my question is arguably a duplicate of that), which links to [this blog post](http://blog.peterlynch.ca/2010/05/maven-how-to-prevent-generate-sources.html) -- in short, it turns out that somewhere along the lines `jar-no-fork` is being added as an execution goal by the maven release plugin. It is only once it reaches Bintray that the duplication is noticed.

Comment: We'll take a look at why it is different across people but I can replicate across VMs -- locally I'm doing what I understand to be a simple `git clone` of master, and then running the same release clean/prepare/publish. What I do not understand is how this can still be open from 2010 ([candidate for 3.7.0 release](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5868)) and not seem to be more widespread.

Comment: Not everybody updates their tools. It might be a version regression. Glad to point to the right direction